# How can I exit a command line input consumer without stopping it's program?

Tags: command-line, bash, suspend

The two commands I know for exiting a running command  input consumer are ctrl^d (suspend) and ctrl^c (stop).

Is there perhaps a third one which says "you go right on ahead, but I'd like to be back in bash".

Essentially, I have a program that while running, it starts up with lots of useful information, and then just logs connections from then on.  I'm interested in the start up info, but once it gets to the logging connections part, I'd like to just go back to where I was before it started, where I end up if I use ctrl^c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *suspend* the program, and then place it in the shell's background.

To suspend a running job, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> - the shell should respond giving you a job id in brackets. You can then background the job using

```
bg <job id>
```

Ex. using `sleep` to mimic your long-running process:

```
$ sleep 100
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 100
$ 
$ bg 1
[1]+ sleep 100 &
$
```

You can obtain a list of running background jobs using `jobs`, and foreground the job again if you wish to do so using `fg <job id>`.

For further information, refer to the `JOB CONTROL` section of `man bash`.